# MySQL Simple Query Improvement with Large Rows

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a simple query across a 20 million record table, and I need a index that will improve the select statement for the following query:

```
 SELECT count(item_id), count(distinct user_id)
 FROM activity
 INNER JOIN item on item.item_id = activity.item_id
 WHERE item.item_id = 3839 and activity.created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

I have a index on:

```
activity - activity_id (PRIMARY), item_id, created_at - All Single Index
item - item_id (PRIMARY)
```

With items that have a lot of content (like 600k), it takes like 4-5 seconds to run the query.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't understand how you are describing your indexes - please provide the SQL used to generate the tables and indexes.

Comment: Yes, also provide the execution plan.

Comment: And which table is `user_id` from?

Comment: User_id is from the activity table.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from `activity` to `item` (and assuming that `user_id` is in table `activity`), then your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM activity
WHERE item_id = 3839 
  AND created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) ;
```

which should be more efficient as it has to get data from only one table or just one index. An index on `(item_id, created_at, user_id)` would be useful.